# How to import a csv file containing duplicate column names in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to import a CSV file with duplicate column names in SAS. Example

**name abc abc def def**

Are the column names in my file.

When i try to import the file in SAS it automatically renames the variables as var1, var2 etc.

I want to retain the original column names. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it a few different ways.  The easiest way to do your example as shown:

```
data want;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input name $ abc1-abc2 def1-def2;
datalines;
John,1,2,3,4
Jack,4,5,6,7
;;;;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Obviously the 1-2 can become 1-35 or whatever.

If your data is more complicated than that, with interleaved variables, I would recommend reading in the header row only, transposing it, and constructing an input statement from that.

```
data varnames; *this dataset reads the header in only - use infile with obs option for actual csv;
input varname $ @@;
order+1; *so we can get back to proper order;
datalines;
Name abc abc def def
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=varnames; *sort by varname;
by varname;
run;

data input_statement;
set varnames;
by varname;
if first.varname then counter=0;
if not (first.varname and last.varname) then do; *if this is not the only varname with same varname;
 counter+1;                          *increment counter;
 varname=cats(varname,counter);      *append counter to varname;
end;
run;

proc sort data=input_statement;   *back to correct order;
by order;
run;

proc sql;   *select the new names into a macro variable;
select varname into :namelist separated by ' ' from input_statement;
quit;

data want;  *input them;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input (&namelist) ($);  *here I just make them all CHAR.  If you have all NUM except the name var, 
                         you could leave name out of your datasets and include it separately.;
datalines;
John,1,2,3,4
Jack,4,5,6,7
;;;;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000314361.htm) it looks like you would put your variable names in the first row and use `GETNAMES=yes`.

```
proc import datafile="C:\temp\test.csv"
   out=shoes
   dbms=csv
   replace;
   getnames=yes;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Comment: When i tried importing using the import wizard and the same code what you posted was run and it automatically renamed the columns

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicated column names in a SAS dataset. You'll have to rename them to something; if you don't like what `proc import` is doing, you can rename them manually via `proc datasets`.

```
proc datasets;
    modify <dataset>;
    rename var1=name var2=abc1 var3=abc2 var4=def1 var5=def2;
quit;
```

Comment: What if the number of columns are too many, how can i then rename them manually?

Comment: Is there any way by which i can make SAS add numeric suffixes to the duplicates such as abc abc1 abc 2 for the columns with name abc?

Comment: yes there is use importdata from file->import data

Comment: if anyone solved this please post the solution